# Run the jquery function when asp.net button click event finish

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i write a simple code in asp.net button click event,for example i write this:

```
Label1.text="Hello Stackoverflow!";
```

i want when up code finish,call the my jquery function,for much explain:
when the asp.net button click source finish run the my jquery function and alert to user.
my jquery code in html page is:

```
(function ($) {
        // DOM Ready
        $(function () {
            // Binding a click event
            // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
            $('#Button1').bind('click', function (e) {
                // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                e.preventDefault();
                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

thanks.

Comment: could you be a bit clearer mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

Use [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx) - 
It will Registers a startup script block with the ScriptManager control and adds the script block to the page.

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Label1.text="Hello Stackoverflow!";
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "AlertFunction", "alert('Your message here...');", true);
// OR
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "AlertFunction", "JqueryFunctionName()", true);

    }
```

- **And** in .aspx file

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
     function JqueryFunctionName(){
           $('#Button1').trigger("click"); // REMOVE THIS LINE
          $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup(); // ADD THIS LINE
     }
</script>
```

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - Check out the Code.

Comment: thanks to pay attention to my problem,i update my question please review.@Prog

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi  Try `$('#Button1').trigger("click");` as above code

Comment: thanks,it's work,but my jquery run and hang the my page! @Prog

Comment: function JqueryFunctionName() {
            $('#Button1').trigger("click");
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

        } run and #element_to_pop_up    run and hang the page @Prog

Comment: but why You use `e.preventDefault();` -?? you need to just use `trigger()` as above code

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - Glad to Help you :) - `upvote` the answer. It will helps other to find correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by making use ajax events.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            //functions to be called before request is sent
        },
        complete: function () {
            // Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete
        },
      ajaxSuccess: function()
{
///call function after success of request
}
    });
});
```

calling of popup should go with either success or complete event.